# Parallel Jobs running across both E and P cores together

Tags: python-3.x

Most of the python programs that I run use the multiprocessing module to split the workload across the entire CPU. On a newer intel machine with E-cores, will slower cores affect my performance if I also use some P-cores in the process.

My worry is that the slower cores will not be able to handle the evenly split processing load, or will lag behind the faster cores. Has anyone made a module that can split the processes according to the power of the specific core. If not I may make my own.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Just split the workload into small enough units and you’ll be fine.